# Environment Variable not sticking

Tags: windows, command-line

I've recently shifted back to Windows 7 and am trying to use Renderman's shader compiler.
It requires that `RMANTREE` be set to

```
C:\Program Files\Pixar]RendermanStudio-3.0.3-maya2012\rmantree
```

So I had set up my mac terminal to have that as an environment variable and never needed to set it again.

On Windows, I can get it to set `RMANTREE` but I have to do it in every command prompt.
I tried adding it to the system environment variables but if I were then to

`echo %RMANTREE%`, I only get `%RMANTREE%` back instead of the correct path.

Probably a stupid question, but any ideas? It would just save a little bit of time, but even a little bit is awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting it in System Environment Variables should give you the behaviour you are after.

Make sure you start a new command prompt once set up.

Comment: it's weird...I did those and restarted the system just to make sure. For some reason Windows dumped the entry I made. So I created it again and now it's working fine.

Moody computer I guess. Thank you though!

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site.  Don't forget to either add your own answer and accept it, or accept my answer so this question gets off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a persistent User or System-wide environment variable.

To set the variable permanently for your **user**, use `setx` from a command prompt:

```
setx RMANTREE "C:\Program Files\Pixar]RendermanStudio-3.0.3-maya2012\rmantree"
```

To set the variable permanently for the entire **system**, add the `/m` switch:

```
setx /m RMANTREE "C:\Program Files\Pixar]RendermanStudio-3.0.3-maya2012\rmantree"
```

You can check if a **specific** environment variable is sourced by using the `set` (no "x"):

```
set RMANTREE
```

Or check all variables **starting with a given letter**:

```
set R
```

And no, it's not a stupid question.

edit: 
The change to the variable will show in all future CMD windows; NOT in the current CMD window.